# Gradle build works fine in Intellij but EXACTLY the same build script fails with 100+ errors on the command line

Tags: gradle

Running the gradle build inside IntelliJ IDEA works fine. If though I run it from the command line it fails giving an error on every single character of the src.

"Execution failed for task ':compileJava'."

I am guessing that it is not able to find the compiler which is odd because running javac from the same command line shows it is live and kicking.

This is one of those moments when I am truly stumped. Is this a bug? Does IDEA insert something to stop you using the command line with the same build script? Surely all the IDEA is doing is reaching out to the command line anyway?

Any help greatly appreciated thanks.

EDIT:

The error on the command line includes **hundreds** of this kind:

/***.java:89:

unclosed character literal
                '±', '§', '~', '`', '\'',
                         ^

/***.java:94:

illegal start of type
        for (int x = 0; x < forbidden.length; x++) {
        ^

/***.java:94:

')' expected
        for (int x = 0; x < forbidden.length; x++) {
                  ^

Literally every single line in a class file throws an error. Like I said, compiling using IDEA built in build process is fine as it using the Jet Gradle plugin. Also, on the command line the gradle clean task works fine too.

Comment: How exactly do you run the Gradle build inside IDEA? What's the *exact* (and complete) error message you get on the command line?

Comment: I am using the JetGradle plugin in IDEA.

Comment: have edited original message to include a section of the command line errors - thanks for taking the time to look at it Peter.

Comment: IntelliJ will tell jetGradle what JDK to use when it runs, your JAVA_HOME/GRADLE_HOME might not be setup correctly.

Comment: I get the same error. Intellij says success but command line is fails.

Comment: In my case, in command line JAVA_HOME was incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

It might not be related but I had similar problems in Intellij today where Gradle command line was failing with many compilation failures but Intellij showed no problems.  This happened after a considerable refactor of project module names. Naturally I assume the IDE was wrong as its a more complex thing than the command line.  I found in two separate instances I needed slightly different approaches!!

**Solution 1**

The solution for me was in intellij **Build->"Rebuild Project"** followed by a **"Refresh all Gradle projects"** button which is the blue circular arrows button at top of the "Gradle" tool window (**View->"Tool Windows"->Gradle**)

**Solution 2**

In another instance I also had to first delete all of the intellij external libraries using **Ctrl-Alt-Shift-S** to open projects Strucutre window.  Then under libraries delete them all. I then followed this up with a **"Refresh all Gradle projects"** as mentioned above

Im not entirely sure what the gradle refresh button is doing really.  At the end of the day both steps are, because of, and a solution to, an extra layer of complexity imposed by the IDE.  Rule:  Always trust the command line and beat on your IDE when its not making sense.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with the follow

```
.
├── build.gradle
├── hello-world
├── plugin
│   └── hello-world
└── settings.gradle

3 directories, 2 files
```

build.gradle

```
rootProject.name = "root-hello-world"
```

settings.gradle

```
include ':hello-world'
include ':plugin:hello-world'
```

by some motive intellij confuses `:plugin:hello-world` with `:hello-world`, in my case **to solve it**:

- rename `hello-world` module folder
- close intellij project
- clear project folder

  ```
  rm -r `find . -type d -name "build"`
  rm `find -name "*.iml"`
  rmdir `find . -type d -empty`
  rm -r .gradle/ .idea/
  ```
- import the project again

Not sure if set something like `project.name = plugin-hello-world` in submodule works

**Obs:** as said on gradle line command the build always works, even when it fails on intellij